# Ionic 2 no access to /@types/cordova plugins

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, cordova-plugins, typescript2.0

I am having problems accessing cordova plugins with the latest ionic 2 release. I have previously used Cordova with an earlier version of Ionic 2 but since the **typings folder** is now moved to "node_modules" and changed to "@types"(in particular "@types/cordova") I no longer seem to be able to access the **cordova.X plugins**.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can find most of the cordova plugins added to ionic-native package [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/)

To add it to project: `ionic plugin add plugin_name --save`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that! And how about the ones that are not added?

Comment: That depends on the plugin..which are you trying to use?

Comment: Yeah, yeah, I know, I get that. I was just wondering if in the near future there is something that's not on there, what the way of doing it would be.

Comment: will have to see how to import type declaration of the plugin, what to set in config.xml and wha is the global object to refer..